# Passing extra data in $_POST vars

Tags: php, forms, wordpress

I need to pass an id along with a form field e.g

```
<input name="__field_name" value="1234" />
```

this only passes the name and value as a key => value pair. i need to keep the name (dynamically entered by the user) and value intact for later use, but i also need to pass an ID along with this var.

how can i do this cleanly? i was thinking putting it in the name and doing a regex to seperate it e.g.

```
__field_name__ID
```

although this seems messy...

points to consider:

- there are allot of post variables that are generated by the CMS (wordpress) that i wont use
- name must be retained in original format along with value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not submit the data as an array?

Instead of calling your field `__field_name__id` or some mess, use the facilities PHP provides: Call your input field `field_name[id]` and when the form is posted back to the server, PHP's `$_POST` array will have a sub-array called `field_name` which contains the key=>value mappings you'd mentioned.

If you have two such fields you want to tie together, use the following:

```
<input type="text" name="myFields[id]" />
<input type="text" name="myFields[name]" />
```

And on postback, PHP will provide you with a `$_POST['myFields']['id']` and `$_POST['myFields']['name']`.

Comment: I have been developing in php for years, i was aware of single dimensional arrays like this.. but for some reason i never thought multidimentional arays were posible! lol

Answer (score 0):

You could add a hidden field which contains the input field name value.

```
<input type="text" name="field_1" />
<input type="hidden" name="field_1_name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a hidden form field which contains the Id of the first field. You can name it as field1_ID or something.

```
<input type="text" name="first_field" value="As_Entered_By_User"/>
<input type="hidden" name="first_field_id" value="id_first_field"/>
```

Or if you are familiar with Javascript, You can post it using javascript with single form field putting the id as an attribute.

```
<input type="text" name="first_field" id="first_field_id" value="as_enteredBy_user"/>
<script>var id_to_post=document.form1.first_field.id;</script>
```

here form1 is the name of the form containing the input box.